# How can I center a dropdown in Twitterbootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a hard time trying to center a dropdown which is toggled by a button in a group. The group is centered correctly but the dropdown continues at the left corner.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/QFkbP/2/).

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like that : [Live demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/LAUsn/)

```css
.centered {
    text-align: center;
}
.centered .dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 500px; /* Needs to be big enough for the menu to be centered in it */
}
.centered .dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle btn" id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="#">
        Dropdown
        <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
            <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit** completed the CSS

Comment: What is the las rule for? It looks like it doesn't affect anything.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov Indeed, forgot some of the CSS to center it (instead of just filling the container).

Comment: Didn't check if it is a crossbrowser solution but it seems that if it's not THE solution, it'll put me in a way to it.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center your `div.dropdown` inside another `div` do it like so:

```
#dropdown1 {
    width: 183px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}​
```

The drawback of it is that you need to know the exact width of the element you are centering (thats the reason I use an id as a selector; of course you need to assing it first).

See how it works on your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QFkbP/8/).

Comment: Not exactly the kind of solution I was looking for as it has to be specific for each dropdrown or I would have to dynamically get/set the widths. But it will help till I find a better way to do that. Thanks a lot!